# How do you write a django model that can automatically normalize data?

Tags: python, django

I'm building a music recommendation engine that uses the lyrics of a track to figure out how closely songs are related to each other emotionally. I've used the tfidf algorithm(not shown here) to generate a score for each song and I'd like to store the tfidf score for each track in a django model field called `tfidf`. But I'd like to normalize each tfidf score along a scale of 0-1.

The difficulty I'm having is in figuring out how to automatically normalize these tfidf scores as soon as someone enters a tfidf value in the admin interface. So imagine that you've gone into the admin interface and want to add the song "In Da Club" to the database. You type in the name of the song and its tfidf score like so:

[image]

What I'd like to do is ensure that as soon as you hit the save button, it automatically populates the empty `normalized_tfidf` column with the normalized value. I'm using a simple algorithm to normalize the tfidf value. Before I go into it though, let me show you what this table would look like so that you have a clearer picture of what the algorithm is doing. So, after "In Da Club" has been added to the database(and data has been normalized), the table columns should look something like this:

[image]

Song x and song y are just dummy songs i've seeded the database with to set an upper and lower bound for the algorithm to work on. That value of `.50077` that you see is what I'm trying to get to automatically generate.

The algorithm says that to find the normalized value (nv) of  feature tfidf in song x , find the difference between the song’s tfidf score and the smallest tfidf score in the table, and divide that by the difference between the maximum and minimum tfidf score in the table. Here it is mathematically.

nv(In da club*tfidf*) = (In da club*tfidf* – tfidf*min*) / (tfidf*max* – tfidf*min*)

And here’s the calculation:

nv(In da club) = (.25048 - .00010) / (.50000 - .00010) = **.50077**

So I'm trying to code that into my model. The problem is that django doesn't seem to have the methods that would allow me to select minimum and maximum tfidf values in a table the way I could with SQL statements. I'm pretty new to django and am not fully aware of what it's capable of. If my model for this table looks like what I have below, what would be the best way to go about rewriting it so that tfidf is automatically normalized once you type it into the admin?

```py
class Party(models.Model):
    song = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tfidf = models.FloatField()
    normalized_tfidf = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: What about the "special cases", where a new tfidf value is outside the min/max range, or an old tfidf value is changed or deleted, possibly setting a different min/max range? I'd probably go for a raw SQL statement for such cases. Could be executed in the save() function, after the super() call, or be "hidden" in a database trigger. Now we need to talk about concurrency, database size, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to trigger some action when a model is saved: override the `save` method, or write a `post_save` listener. I'll show the override method since it's a little simpler, and fits this use case nicely.

To to get the max / min, you can use Django's [queryset aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation):

```
from django.db.models import Max, Min


class Party(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        max = Party.objects.all().aggregate(Max('tfidf'))['tfidf__max']
        min = Party.objects.all().aggregate(Min('tfidf'))['tfidf__min']
        self.normalized_tfidf = (self.tfidf - min) / (max - min)
        super(Party, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Overriding default model methods like `save` is pretty straightforward but there's some more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) if you're interested.

Note that if you are doing [bulk updates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) to `Party.tfidf` at any point, the save handler won't get called (or post_save signals sent, for that matter), so you'd have to process all of the rows manually - which would mean a lot of DB writes and would pretty much make doing bulk updates pointless.

Comment: Thanks for  the helpful response. When I try to run the dev server however, I get the following error...not sure what's causing it: File "/Users/mikaschiller/Documents/djangoprojects/twizzle/models.py", line 35
    min = Party.objects.all().aggregate(Min('tfidf')['tfidf__min']
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Looks like you are missing a ')'. Should be Party.objects.all().aggregate(Min('tfidf'))['tfidf__min'] - which I see I also missed in my answer. Editing now...

Answer (score 0):

To prevent issues with stale data, etc., as mentioned by @klaws in the comments above, it may not be ideal to calculate the normalized value at the time a new song is added.

Instead, you could use a query that lets the database calculate the normalized value, whenever it is needed.

You'll need to import some stuff from django's [expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) and [aggregates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions):

```
from django.db.models import Window, F, Min, Max
```

Here's a simple example, applied to the OP's problem, assuming no grouping is needed:

```py
def query_normalized_tfidf(party_queryset):
    w_min = Window(expression=Min('tfidf'))
    w_max = Window(expression=Max('tfidf'))
    return party_queryset.annotate(
        normalized_tfidf=(F('tfidf') - w_min) / (w_max - w_min))
```

The `Window` class allows us to continue annotating the individual objects, as explained e.g. [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html) and in Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions).

Instead of using a separate query function, we could also add this to a custom [model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).

If you need the normalized values to be calculated with respect to certain groups (e.g. if the song had a `genre`), the above could be extended, and generalized, as follows:

```py
def query_normalized_values(queryset, value_lookup, group_lookups=None):
    """
    a generalized version that normalizes data with respect to the
    extreme values within each group
    """
    partitions = None
    if group_lookups:
        partitions = [F(group_lookup) for group_lookup in group_lookups]
    w_min = Window(expression=Min(value_lookup), partition_by=partitions)
    w_max = Window(expression=Max(value_lookup), partition_by=partitions)
    return queryset.annotate(
        normalized=(F(value_lookup) - w_min) / (w_max - w_min))
```

This could be used as follows, assuming there would be a `Party.genre` field:

```py
annotated_parties = query_normalized_values(
    queryset=Party.objects.all(), value_lookup='tfidf',
    group_lookups=['genre'])
```

This would normalize the `tfidf` values with respect to the extreme `tfidf` values within each `genre`.

Note: In the special case of division by zero (when `w_min` equals `w_max`), the resulting "normalized value" will be `None`.